# Place UIButton at the end of text in UITextView in iOS app in Xcode written in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextview

In one `ViewController` of my app there's a `UITextView`. I want to have an "Allow Push Notifications" button at the end of the text. But since a button is static a the text in the `TextView` is dynamical depending on display width it looks really bad on some devices and orientations.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Is there a possibility to insert a button in a `TextView`. Or can I align the button depending from `TextView` content height?

Regards,
David.

Comment: why a text view and not a label?

Comment: @luiyezheng Actually the button is centered horizontally and vertically. It looks okay on most devices except on 4” and 3,5" devices.

Comment: @Wain Because there are ca. six sentences.

Comment: does the user edit it?

Comment: No, it's not editable.

Answer (score 7):

`UITextView` subclasses from `UIScrollView`, you can use this to your advantage to add subviews to it as you would any normal `UIScrollView`, the trick is to offset the text view's text container by the height of the button + padding. For example:

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 500))
textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae fermentum tellus. Donec dui sem, viverra eu auctor eleifend, aliquet id lorem. Nam id sapien sed arcu auctor commodo nec nec nulla. Praesent id mi nec odio consequat varius id sit amet quam."

let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 44
let contentInset: CGFloat = 8

//inset the textView
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: contentInset, left: contentInset, bottom: (buttonHeight+contentInset*2), right: contentInset)

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: contentInset, y: textView.contentSize.height - buttonHeight - contentInset, width: textView.contentSize.width-contentInset*2, height: buttonHeight))

//setup your button here
button.setTitle("BUTTON", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

//Add the button to the text view
textView.addSubview(button)
```

This will give you the following output:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: Do I have to put a UITextView and a UIButton in my ViewController on my Storyboard?

Comment: …and create  @IBOutlet's?

Comment: You can add the textfield to your view controller via your storyboard or programatically, it's best if the button is added programatically.