# Buttons in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uitextview

I want to create a View very similar To the iOS notes application. The main function is to allow the user to get a check box in front of a line of Text.

[image]

My first attempt is this:
I have a `UITextView` where i try to insert buttons on the left side of the View, the Problem is i dont get the right y Position for each line and the whole text is offsetted even if there is no Button in Front of the line.

Question:
Is there a better approach, maybe much simpler or even built in functionality in `UITextView` i couldn‘t find?
If not, how do i get the exact y position of the line the cursor is currently in, so i can set the Buttons in the correct positions?

Comment: can you please add screenshot of what you want to achieve so we can get better idea

Comment: Please check 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803423/swift-checkbox-insertion-in-uitextview-of-a-uitableviewcell-and-using-uitapgest

it seems similar to your question.